# Why Perl will replace # by %23 in a system call?

Tags: macos

The following Perl code doesn't open the url as expected:

```
$word="中文";
my $url="http://www.google.com/#source=hp&q=" . $word;
print $url . "\n";
system("open \"$url\"");
```

It opens Google chrome with URL:

```
http://www.google.com/%23source=hp&q=中文
```

instead of

```
http://www.google.com/#source=hp&q=中文
```

If i replace the system call by

```
system("echo \"$url\"");
```

it prints correct URL `http://www.google.com/#source=hp&q=中文` which works when pasted in to the URL field of Google Chrome.

Why is this? How to fix it?

[Edit Aug. 14, 20:30CDT]

It seems the problem is with `open`. None of

```
open "http://www.google.com/#source=hp&q=中文"
open 'http://www.google.com/#source=hp&q=中文'
open http://www.google.com/#source=hp&q=中文
```

works. They all mistakenly replaced `#` with `%23`. Interestingly, if i only put 1 character in the query, i.e. use "中" instead of "中文", I found both

```
open "http://www.google.com/#source=hp&q=中"
open 'http://www.google.com/#source=hp&q=中'
```

work but not

```
open http://www.google.com/#source=hp&q=中
```

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes instead of double quotes in the system call? Like so:

`system("open '$url'");`

Comment: Have you tried running the 'open' command directly from a shell? The problem might not be with per, but with how open and or chrome handles URLs from the command line.

Comment: Did you try to set different default browsers? Is it the same for Firefox, Safari and Chrome?

Comment: Tried different browsers; No difference.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to the original question is: it doesn't.  (I don't get credit for that; the OP mentioned that in an edit of the question.)

As the OP said when editing the question, it's definitely the `open` command, not Perl or `system()`, that's doing this (and using single rather than double quotes shouldn't make any difference).

Note that `open` seems to be specific to MacOS (there's an `open` command on my Ubuntu system, but it's not the same thing).  [Here's the man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html).

*Part* of the explanation is that `%23` is the hexadecimal representation of the `'#"` character.  URLs commonly use this mechanism to escape characters that would otherwise have some meaning in a URL.  For example, entering `"foo#bar"` in the google.com search box produces this url: [http://www.google.com/search?q=%22foo%23bar%22](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22foo#bar%22).

The question is, why is `open` replacing `'#'` by `%23` when it *should* be treated as a metacharacter?  That may be a bug in `open`, or there might be a way to work around it.  Perhaps someone more familar with MacOS can help out with that.

Just a wild guess: what happens if you type

```
open 'http://www.google.com/\#source=hp&q=中文'
```

on the command line?

Comment: With your suggestion, it opens `http://www.google.com/%5C%23source=hp&q=中文`, which is wrong too.